# Recording narration for a game

Tags: rpg, audio

I am the narrator for a RPG game I'm creating. I have two questions:

1) **Quality**: I have a mic that seems to pick up a lot of background static along with my voice, so the overall quality sounds terrible. Is there a specific type of mic that should be used for game narration?

2) **Performance**: Narration quality is important for the game, but there will be many audio files. Is there a method to delivering quality audio files while compressing the file? Since it's narration, I need the audio to be snappy and clear.

Comment: I'd say you should ask this on an audio-focused SE, but I guess we don't have one? [This guy](http://www.marco.org/podcasting-microphones) has done a nice round-up of mics from a podcasting perspective, which may have overlapping requirements with your narration needs.

Comment: I am not an expert on microphones, so I am not qualified to write a full answer. But modern audio codecs like OGG and even the dated MP3 can compress so well that there is barely an audible difference - if the recording is good. White noise has high entropy, which means it compresses very badly and can cause really weird artifacts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quality** - No, not really.  I've made quality audio files with the cheap mic that came with my computer over 20 years ago.  Nowadays, though, when that doesn't cut it I use the same mic I use for music, which is a Shure SM58.  Use a pop filter and/or the noise reduction features of your recording software.  Lowering the gain/recording volume of your mic will also cut down on general background noise.  You don't, as previously suggested, need to build a sound booth.  I've worked on professional projects where the audio was recorded in the office.  The sound engineer just closed the door and told everyone to keep it down while they were working.  Read the reviews of various USB/DI mics in your budget range and pick the one you like the best.

**Performance** - The lowest sampling rate I've used was 11khz.  It sounded fine, but it wasn't "granular" enough for the lip-synching software I was using to pick up much in the way of nuances.  You should probably just stick to the default 44khz, 16-bit standard that most recording is done at.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a lot but preventing the background noise from reaching the mic.

This requires building a sound booth of some description where you will be recording your voice.

For which microphone to use is offtopic here. A crap setup will give crap quality. The 3.5mm microphone jack you will find on most computers will not give good quality.

Answer (score 0):

Well, talking about the quality thing, I think yeah mic does play a role but even a decent mic can do the job, I have done this for recording my voice in walkthrough videos for my gaming channel, I would suggest you to use audacity, its a great free tool available learn how to use it efficiently by seeing YouTube videos, it is going to help for sure.
And about the performance adobe audacity can be very helpful here to deliver good and compressed quality audio file.